# google map inside a hidden div problems

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, hidden

Trying to hide a google map until the zipcode form field is filled but I'm getting a grey box. I did research and know I need to re-size the map because of my hidden div but not very good with coding.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
   $(function () {    
        $('#zip-search-box').change(function() {
            $('.map-canvas').toggle($(this).val().length !== 0);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
            map.setCenter(center);                           
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="zipFilter">
    <label for="zip-search-box">Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip-search-box" name="zip-search-box" />
    <label for="zip-search-radius">Radius:</label>
    <select id="zip-search-radius" name="zip-search-radius">
      <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
      <option value="10">10 Miles</option>
      <option value="20" selected="true">20 Miles</option>
      <option value="25">25 Miles</option>
      <option value="30">30 Miles</option>
      <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
      <option value="100">100 Miles</option>
      <option value="200">200 Miles</option>
    </select>
 <button id="zip-search-bttn" name="zip-search-bttn">Search</button>
    <button id="map-reset" name="map-reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="map-canvas" id="google-map"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map-canvas { 
display: none; 
}
```

Comment: you mean show map when '#zip-search-box' change?

Comment: yes. I can't seem to get the map to resize. Looks like this after I show map: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GmzSV.jpg

Answer (score 0):

show one element with jQuery:

```
$("#element id").show(); or fadeIn();
```

or

```
$(".element class").show();
```

readmore with fadeIn completed function to show element :)

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

with toggle callback http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle_callback

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle(1000,function(){
      alert("The toggle() method is finished!");
    });
  });
```

this bug is map called reside when map-canvas doesn't reside yet, callback function completed toggle function and reside map when map-canvas resided. :)

hope this help

Comment: I already have the map shown in my code by #zip-search-box change, I need it to resize to show correctly. It currently looks like this asfter show: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GmzSV.jpg

Comment: Still not really what i am wanting.  Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/granato/mvd6gfL8/12/

Comment: Your code have a bug **map is not defined** at lines 4,5